# how to check for file changes in GitLab CI, but only if merging into default branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, rules

After having to manually update my repo because I forgot to change the version number... twice, I decided it was time for some CI magic.

Here's the deal: if I make a Merge Request into `main`, I expect the application version number to have changed in 3 different files.

Here is my code so far:

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

workflow:
  # some rules

unit_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    # run UT

# This is the part the question is about
check_version:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE' == "merge_request_event" && '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME' == '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      changes:
        - composer.json
        - resources/index.php
        - Doxyfile

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    # deployment script
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH' == '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
```

If I understood things correctly, what I did is "If it's a Merge Request into `main`, check for changes in `composer.json`, `resources/index.php` and `Doxyfile`".

First: is it correct?

Second: what do I do to allow pushes and Merge Requests in other branches? Is there some kind of "else" that follows the "if"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the `rules` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges), the way you have it is correct based on the description of what you want. If a pipeline is run for a Push event, for a different branch, or if no changes are included for those three files, the `check_version` job will not be added to the pipeline (you won't even see it in the pipeline diagram), and all other jobs will run based on their own `rules` clause, if any, or an explicit `when` clause.

However, others working on your project might find this way confusing, so personally I always add an explicit `when:never` in these cases:

```yaml
...
check_version:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE' == "merge_request_event" && '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME' == '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      changes:
        - composer.json
        - resources/index.php
        - Doxyfile
    - when: never
...
```

This will end up with the same result as your example in your question, but in my opinion is more clear. When this is evaluated during the push/merge request/trigger/etc. event, if the `if` conditional passes, the job is added to the pipeline. Otherwise, it [explicitly] isn't.

Comment: Excellent, `when: never` corresponds to that `else` I was looking for. This is perfect, thanks!

Comment: One note about the `rules` keyword, multiple clauses are only ever interpreted as logical OR, no matter if it's multiple if's, a separate `when` clause like above, etc., it's interpreted as `OR`. The only way to get a logical AND is in the same conditional, like in your example.

Comment: That is such a simple explanation, thank you! `- X ⏎ Y` is AND, `- X ⏎ - Y` is OR, brilliant!